# Erro setItemOnClickListener após clique

Tags: android, listview

Estou tendo um problema na aplicação onde após eu fazer o clique em alguma linha do meu `ListView`, o aplicativo simplesmente crasha (não conseguindo ver o erro no Debugger).

A ideia é após o click na `ListView` os dados da linha irem para o `EditText` na minha outra `Activity`.

Segue o código abaixo:

```
    public class FillList extends AsyncTask <String,String,String> {
    String z="";
    List<Map<String, String>> prolist = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    @Override public void onPreExecute()
    {
        progbar2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override public  void onPostExecute(String r){
        progbar2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //Toast.makeText(MegaPermanentes_Usuarios.this, r, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        String[] from = {"A", "B"};
        int[] views = {R.id.lblproname, R.id.lblproend};
        final SimpleAdapter ADA = new SimpleAdapter(MegaPermanentes_Usuarios.this, prolist, R.layout.lsttemplate, from, views);
        listPro.setAdapter(ADA);

        listPro.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //Bundle params = new Bundle();
                String resposta = (String) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                Intent it = new Intent(MegaPermanentes_Usuarios.this, MegaPermanentes.class);
                it.putExtra("nome",resposta);
                startActivity(it);

            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try{
            Connection con = connectionClass.connectionclass();
            if(con == null){
                z = "Conexão falhou";
            }else
                {
                String query = "select nome,endereco from usuarios";
                PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

                while(rs.next()){
                    Map<String, String> datanum = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    datanum.put("A", rs.getString ("Nome"));
                    datanum.put("B", rs.getString("Endereco"));
                    prolist.add(datanum);
                }


            }


        }catch (Exception ex)
        {
            z = "Error Retrieving Data";
        }
        return z;
    }


}
```

Aqui a parte do `onItemClickListener`:

```
 listPro.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //Bundle params = new Bundle();
                String resposta = (String) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                Intent it = new Intent(MegaPermanentes_Usuarios.this, MegaPermanentes.class);
                it.putExtra("nome",resposta);
                startActivity(it);

            }
        });
```

Comment: tente recuperar a String resposta = ADA.getItem(position)

Comment: Ficaria assim? `String resposta = (String) ADA.getItem(position);`? Ainda assim esta crashando.

Comment: A classe *MegaPermanentes* está registrada no AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @LeonardoDias, sim: `</activity>
        <activity android:name=".MegaPermanentes" />
        <activity android:name=".MegaPermanentes_Usuarios"></activity>`

Comment: Tenta fazer dessa forma então: **String resposta = (String) (listPro.getItemAtPosition(position));**

Comment: Sim, na verdade seria String resposta = (String) ADA.getItem(position).get("A"); Pois o getItem está te retornando um HashMap

Comment: @AndréOzawa ficaria `.get("A")` mesmo? No AS não reconheceu essa sintaxe.

Comment: @LeonardoDias sem avanço também, continua crashando no mesmo momento em que eu clico no `ListView`.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que dar-se pra perceber, você cria um objeto usando o `Map` e insere em cada item do seu `ListView`. Sendo assim, para recuperar os dados, você deve também usar o `Map`. Veja abaixo um exemplo:

```
// recuperando o valor do item após o click
Map<String, String> obj = (Map<String, String>) getAdapter().getItem(position);
// recuperando o nome
String name = (String) obj.get("A");
// recuperando o endereço
String address = (String) obj.get("B");
```

Comment: não estou conseguindo utilizar o método `getAdapter` após o `(Map<String, String)`